# Issue with using tf.vectorized_map on a function with a tf.while_loop (TF 2.0)

Tags: python, vectorization, tensorflow2.0

The included minimum working example tries to vectorize a function which adds 10.0 to the input and does so through a while loop which adds 1.0 each time (for 10 times). The function runs perfectly when using tf.map_fn and fails when using tf.vectorized_map.

The function would not run when using vectorized map and the error points towards `Either add a converter or set --op_conversion_fallback_to_while_loop=True`, which may run slower.
What am I doing wrong? Note: This is an duplicate of the same question I asked https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/46559.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import tensorflow as tf
    @tf.function()
    def add(a):       
        i = tf.constant(0, dtype = tf.int32)
        c = tf.constant(1., dtype = tf.float32)
        loop_index = lambda  i, c, a: i < 10
        def body(i, c, a):
            a = c + a
            i = i + 1
            return i,c, a
        i,c, a = tf.while_loop(loop_index, body, [i,c, a],\
             shape_invariants=[tf.TensorShape(()), tf.TensorShape(()),tf.TensorShape([1])], back_prop= False, parallel_iterations=1)

        return a

    counter =  tf.reshape(tf.range(0, 40, delta = 1, dtype = tf.float32), shape = [40,1])

    all_ = tf.vectorized_map(add, counter) # does not work
    # all_ = tf.map_fn(add, counter) # works as expected
    print(all_, '<-- should be [40,1] float32 tensor with elements [10., 11., ...49.]')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately this issue is only reproducible with **TF2.2.0 + CUDA 10.1** on a **conda** environment, and there is nothing wrong with the code. The fix is to run the code with a different version of tensorflow. This is a collab notebook demonstrating the same from the github issue from the issue assignee ravikyram [Link](https://colab.research.google.com/gist/ravikyram/43c6698c61e793b03cb1f82d0b62f6fd/untitled627.ipynb)